# Finding next occurrence of number in dataframe (Excel MATCH())

Tags: python

All, I've looked around for a solution to my problem, but can't find anything that works in the way I'd like.  I'm trying to use the following script to replicate Excel's MATCH() function to find the next occurrence of the number `1` in the dataframe.  I'm new to coding so might be overlooking something simple.

The example dataset I've created looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'secondcol': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
```

The code I've been trying is this:

```
df['match']=df['secondcol'].index(next(lambda x: x!=0, df['secondcol'])
```

Which gives this error:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not an iterator
```

The desired outcome would be this:

```
       match  secondcol
0      3          0
1      2          0
2      1          0
3      0          1
4      0          1
5      1          0
6      0          1
```

I've looked up the error but cannot figure out how to change the code to remove it.  Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    c+=str(a[i:].index(1))
print(c)
```

Try this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'secondcol': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
b = df["secondcol"].tolist()
c=[b[i:].index(1) for i in range(0,len(b))]
df['match']=c
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit-Pandey.  I tried your suggestion, and am having trouble implementing it.  I also tried 'df['match']=np.nonzero(df['secondcol'])', which also generated an error...I'm continuing to tinker with it, thanks again for your help!

Comment: That second one worked perfectly...thank you very much!

Comment: my apologies, I'm a very new member and don't have the requisite 15 credits for an upvote; I'll try to remember when I get to that level.